# Moving values in multi index and entering total row pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe for recording finances using a UI to input data daily.

```
                            Food  Clothes  Bills  ...  Art  Other  Daily Total
Week End   Today's Date
2020-09-27 2020-09-21         25       25     25  ...   25     25          175
           2020-09-23         20       20     20  ...   20     20          140
           2020-09-24         12       12     12  ...   12     12           84
           2020-09-25         20       20     20  ...   20     20          140
2020-10-04 2020-09-28         12       12     12  ...   12     12           84
           2020-09-29          7        7      7  ...    7      7           49
           2020-09-30          8        8      8  ...    8      8           56
```

I'm trying to now move the Week End multi index to appear after the last day of the week so that I can enter a weekly total row. Here's the desired dataframe;

```
                            Food  Clothes  Bills  ...  Art  Other  Daily Total
Week End   Today's Date
           2020-09-21         25       25     25  ...   25     25          175
           2020-09-23         20       20     20  ...   20     20          140
           2020-09-24         12       12     12  ...   12     12           84
           2020-09-25         20       20     20  ...   20     20          140
2020-09-27                    77       77     77        77     77          539

           2020-09-28         12       12     12  ...   12     12           84
           2020-09-29          7        7      7  ...    7      7           49
           2020-09-30          8        8      8  ...    8      8           56
2020-10-04                    27       27     27        27     27          189
```

Adding a blank row after each week would increase readability, if anyone has any ideas that would be great, thanks in advance. I'm also writing to excel, not sure if this changes anything but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

in case you don't need a VBA code for it:

first fill in the week end column with the weekend date by using special cells (5) >> Blank and write a formula that pulls and value of the cell above
check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ROjmlkFr4A

Now you can choose between Subtotals or a Pivot Table (I would prefer adding a PT)

Subtotals: Data >> Subtotal >>
At each change of: Week End
Use function: sum
Add subtotals: select all columns except the date columns

OR

Pivot Table: Inset >> Pivot Table
Rows: Week End, Today's Date
Values: select all columns except the date columns and the totals (u have Grand totals instead)
for blank rows go to Design >> Blank Rows >> Insert blank row after each item

Comment: It looks like the poster was looking for a solution in Python using the Pandas library, rather than an Excel-based answer